# Get data from server using php

Tags: cocoa-touch

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://nyxmyx.com/Kinkey/KinkeyPHP/lastidretrieve.php"];
    NSData *data = [url resourceDataUsingCache:YES];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"result FOR ID  %@",string);
```

I am using this code in didenterBackgroundMethod.In that i just want to call lastidretrieve.php which returns a response as a string.I am getting  error as "receiver type nsurl for instance message does not declare a method with selector resourceDataUsingCache".i have no idead about this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code instead of your code it gives the string output ,then you have to format that string to get disired output.

```
NSString *post =@"";

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nyxmyx.com/Kinkey/KinkeyPHP/lastidretrieve.php"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
    {
        //NSData *data = [responseData resourceDataUsingCache:YES];
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"responseData-%@",string);
    }
```

Output will be like this.

```
responseData-1995<br />prabu<br />1231231233<br />antab<br />8080808080<br />1360738531881.jpg<br />No
```

**UPDATE**

In case you want to add argument in your URL than change post string to this.

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"yourArg=%@",yourArg];
```

Comment: In case of  one argument how do i change the url?

Comment: when sending one argument i am getting no response

Comment: what argument are you want to send?

Comment: NSString *myString = @"1994";NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"yourArg=%@",myString];

Comment: i am getting empty data response from php side

Comment: this will create your url like this "nyxmyx.com/Kinkey/KinkeyPHP/lastidretrieve.php?yourArg=1994",here mystring is value of your mystring variable.

Comment: can you explain, why you want to pass argument in your url ,your url only return data.

Comment: for that id  i need to get sendermobile number and receiver mobile number

Comment: but your URL does not have any argument field than where you are passing 1994? you have posted your full URL?

Comment: Look, "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=23.0333,72.6167&destination=23.2200,72.6800&sensor=false",this is google map api url,and here origin and destination and sensor are the argument which is accepted by the url, your url does not contain any argument field so whatever you write it will return same data.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been sufficient to read the documentation of `NSURL`. This method is deprecated. You should use `[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]` instead.

Comment: @user2003416 No. It's a one-liner. You figure it out. (Huh. In fact, I've already written in the answer what you need to write.)